# How to group by ID and then find time delta for each new dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to take my time series dataframe, then group by values in a certain column, and then take those new dataframes and find the difference between the last and first timestamps. I cannot figure out if this is ultimately a need for a nested groupby(). I am using python for this.

I will explain here...
I have this dataframe:

```
        CityID                 Timestamp        Rainfall
---------------------------------------------------------
 0         222       2017-03-19 05:06:00               0
 1         222       2017-03-19 05:07:00               5
 2         222       2017-03-19 05:08:00               4
 3         222       2017-03-19 05:09:00               0
 4         222       2017-03-19 05:10:00               0
 5         222       2017-03-19 05:11:00               0
 6         222       2017-03-19 05:12:00               3
 7         222       2017-03-19 05:13:00               3
 8         222       2017-03-19 05:14:00               2
 9         222       2017-03-19 05:15:00               4
10         222       2017-03-19 05:16:00               0
11         222       2017-03-19 05:17:00               5
12         222       2017-03-19 05:18:00               4 
13         222       2017-03-19 05:19:00               4
14         222       2017-03-19 05:20:00               0
15         223       2017-03-19 05:09:00               0
16         223       2017-03-19 05:10:00               3
17         223       2017-03-19 05:11:00               2
18         223       2017-03-19 05:12:00               4
19         223       2017-03-19 05:15:00               0
20         223       2017-03-19 05:16:00               0
21         223       2017-03-19 05:17:00               3
22         223       2017-03-19 05:18:00               2
23         223       2017-03-19 05:19:00               3
24         223       2017-03-19 05:20:00               5
25         223       2017-03-19 05:21:00               4
26         223       2017-03-19 05:24:00               5
27         223       2017-03-19 05:27:00               3 
28         223       2017-03-19 05:28:00               2
29         223       2017-03-19 05:29:00               0
```

What I want to do is identify "storms" for each city, where a storm is identified here as any sequence of non-zero "Rainfall" values (in inches) between 0s. For context, this means that we acknowledge a storm starts at 0 rainfall, and ends at 0 rainfall. If there is a 0 value in between, then that would thereby mean 2 separate storms. Here, yes, a storm can have minimal rainfall and last just a few minutes. I want to groupby each CityID, and produce the following dataframes:

```
222
storm     duration
-------------------
0                1
1                4
2                3

223
storm     duration
-------------------
0                3
1               11
```

These are the dataframes I want to output. I will explain this in more detail. What I did was (or what I want to do) take my original dataframe, group by CityID, then identify each storm, and give it an ID (e.g. 0,1,2, etc.). Then for each storm, within each city, I want to find the time duration. And so for each storm, this means taking the last timestamp and subtracting the first timestamp to produce a time delta (in minutes) for each storm. This would include the time skips in CityID 223, accounting for missing rows. (For delineating storms based on rainfall in the beginning, I ignored missing rainfall data. For finding the total time duration of each storm, I assume that there was non-zero rainfall in the missing rows.)

The goal is to identify all the storms for each city and find their time duration. From this output dataframe I am looking to answer my research questions of "How many storms occurred in each city?" and "How long was each storm?"

I am having a lot of trouble trying to conceptualize how to do this, and while I think I need to use a nested groupby, constructing the code itself is really confusing me. Would anyone here know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: After you've grouped by City ID, you could create a storm number/identifier by 1) sorting each city data frame, 2) identify records with a zero rainfall, and 3) using cumulative sum. e.g. `df['storm_id'] = (df['Rainfall'] == 0).cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. Here is the way to get a delta between two dates:

```
import datetime as dt

def get_delta(d1, d2):
    date1 = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(d1)
    date2 = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(d2)
    return date2 - date1

date1 = "2017-03-19 05:06:00"
date2 = "2017-03-19 05:08:00"

delta = get_delta(date1, date2)

print(delta) # Output: 0:02:00
print(delta.seconds//60) # Output: 2 (minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I used into an analysis like yours:

```
import numpy as np 

# finding the indexes of starting/endings
start, end = np.diff(df.Rainfall !=0, prepend=False, append=False).nonzero()[0].reshape(-1, 2).T
start -= 1 # subtract 1 in order to take the first zero
```

Into this example I used the whole timeseries without grouping the cities.
You can group them with df.loc[df.CityID == ID_city, 'Rainfall']